# What is this piece of Javascript for Isotope filter doing?

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble understanding what is happening in a piece of vanilla JS for the Isotope filter. The original code is here: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/VWLJEb

```
var buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');

for (var i = 0; i < buttonGroups.length; i++) {
  var buttonGroup = buttonGroups[i];
  var onButtonGroupClick = getOnButtonGroupClick(buttonGroup);
  buttonGroup.addEventListener('click', onButtonGroupClick);
}

function getOnButtonGroupClick(buttonGroup) {
  return function(event) {
    // check for only button clicks
    var isButton = event.target.classList.contains('button');
    if (!isButton) {
      return;
    }
    var checkedButton = buttonGroup.querySelector('.is-checked');
    checkedButton.classList.remove('is-checked')
    event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
  }
}
```

What is happening between the getOnButtonGroupClick function and it being assigned to a variable in the for loop preceding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getButtonGroupClick` returns a closure that saves the value of `buttonGroup`. When you click on a button in the button group, it uses that closure variable to search for the checked button in the group, uncheck it, and then check the button you clicked on.

This complexity isn't really needed. When an event listener is called, `event.currentTarget` is set to the element that the listener was attached to, so you could just use that.

```js
var buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');

for (var i = 0; i < buttonGroups.length; i++) {
  var buttonGroup = buttonGroups[i];
  buttonGroup.addEventListener('click', onButtonGroupClick);
}

function OnButtonGroupClick(event) {
  // check for only button clicks
  var isButton = event.target.classList.contains('button');
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  var checkedButton = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.is-checked');
  checkedButton.classList.remove('is-checked')
  event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, It means that a click event is being added to every button in the `buttonGroups` there is. Although, if you ask me, it would be way better and cleaner to just use a `forEach`, like so:

```
const buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');
buttonGroups.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", OnButtonGroupClick)

function OnButtonGroupClick(event) {
  // check for only button clicks
  let isButton = event.target.classList.contains('button');
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }
  let checkedButton = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.is-checked');
  checkedButton.classList.remove('is-checked')
  event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
}
```

So, you add a **click** event to **ALL** the buttons in the `buttonGroups` that will run the function `onButtonGroupClick`.

**EDIT:** And there's no really need to assign the function like that... at all. Just call it on the click event and that's it.

Comment: Do you mean you don't need to call a function each time you click a different button? What would it look like calling it on the click event in general rather than each time?

Comment: No, what I mean is, with this small piece of code that I wrote in the answer, it automatically adds a click event to all the buttons there are defined with the `buttonGroups` variable and that click event will run the function (in this case `onButtonGroupClick`) no matter on which button the user clicked. It's kinda unnecessary made complicated with that for loop, if you ask me and for me it's a bit cleaner and also easier to understand if I need to call some function on multiple buttons, to use forEach.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I am all about efficiency and this code seemed kind of bloated, but I'm not quite to jQuery yet which I think is what Isotope uses mainly. Thanks for this.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, this `forEach` option that I provided isn't part of jQuery, its vanilla JS, if you were reffering to that one :)

Comment: I tried to add this to my code and it works for the filter, but it wouldn't change the color to reflect the current button selection. Can you show me what the code would look like with the .forEach method?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the function below. Upon calling the function `OnButtonGroupClick` you just pass in an `event` or `e` parameter in it, like so: `function OnButtonGroupClick(event) { ... }`

Comment: I see now. I made a mistake with not renaming the function that changes the class of the button. This is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is used to iterate over all of the elements with the class of `button-group` and and a click event listener to them. `getOnButtonGroupClick` returns a function to be used as the function to be used as the event listener for the element i.e. the function that is run when the element is clicked on.

```
var buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');
//get all elements within the document with a class of button-group
//buttonGroups is a NodeList

for (var i = 0; i < buttonGroups.length; i++) {
//loop through all of the elements with a class of button-group matched by the above query selector
  var buttonGroup = buttonGroups[i];
  //get the element in the NodeList with the index i
  var onButtonGroupClick = getOnButtonGroupClick(buttonGroup);
  //get the function to be run when the element is clicked on
  buttonGroup.addEventListener('click', onButtonGroupClick);
  //add a click event listener to the element
}

function getOnButtonGroupClick(buttonGroup) {
  return function(event) {
    // check for only button clicks
    var isButton = event.target.classList.contains('button');
    //check if the element has a class of button
    if (!isButton) {
      //if the element does not have a class of button, do nothing
      return;
    }
    var checkedButton = buttonGroup.querySelector('.is-checked');
    checkedButton.classList.remove('is-checked')
    event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I'm still learning JS and kind of implementing it and modifying it, but I truly want to understand so I really appreciate this. Working through Mozilla's MDN is taking some time.

Comment: @MichaelMcCarthy No problem.